# Google Maps API Tutorial 1 "Putting your data on a map" - (Error with JSON request?)

Tags: json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm currently working through the Google Maps API Tutorial 1 "Putting your data on a map". link here: https://developers.google.com/maps-engine/documentation/tutorial-create-map#step_1_create_an_empty_table_in_google_maps_engine

Sadly, I've been stuck for the past few days at almost the beginning of the tutorial ("step 1: create an empty table in Google Maps Engine"). At the step that links to "google apis explorer maps enginge tables upload", I'm entering my correct and my own projectID, and typing in the rest of the JSON exactly as displayed in the tutorial.

```
This is my request body:
{
    "files":
    [
    {
        "filename":"population-growth.csv"
    }
    {
        "filename":"population-growth.vrt"
    }
    ]
    "name":"Population change"
    "projectId":"************"
    "description":"World population change"
    "tags":
    [
      "population growth"
      "population change"
    ]
    "schema":
    {
        "primaryKey":"COUNTRY"
    }
}

However, I keep receiving this error 

Request:
POST https://www.googleapis.com/mapsengine/v1/tables/upload?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

{
 "name": "Population change",
 "schema": {
  "primaryKey": "COUNTRY"
 },
 "description": "World population change",
 "files": [
  {
   "filename": "population-growth.csv"
  },
  {
   "filename": "population-growth.vrt"
  }
 ],
 "projectId": "************",
 "tags": [
  "population growth",
  "population change"
 ]
}

Response:
400 Bad Request

- Show headers -

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "message": "The specified entity does not exist.",
    "locationType": "other",
    "location": "projectId"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "The specified entity does not exist."
 }
}
```

I don't know how to move past this as I've looked throughout StackOverflow and no answers answer my . Is this a common problem for users of this tutorial? I'd appreciate any advice that you all can give me. Thank you!

Comment: Have you put your `APIKEY` and `project id` correctly?

Comment: Hey sorry for the late reply! Yes I put in my project ID correctly, and there's no place to enter your APIKEY; however, the best I can do is "Authorize requests using OAuth 2.0". I've done both, and I'm still receiving an error.